# How to use CDK Aspects to get all the environment variables of a lambda function in a scope?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I want to get the environment variables and their values of all the lambda function in a scope using CDK Aspects. I have tried defining a custom Aspect, but the `node` object of `Function` construct don't have `environment` property.

```js
class LambdaEnvAspect implements IAspect{
    visit(node: IConstruct): void {
        if(node instanceof lambda.Function ) {
            const vars = node.environment // environment property doesn't exist
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried using L1 construct of the lambda function but I am not able to resolve the output into an object

```js
class LambdaEnvAspect implements IAspect{

    visit(node: IConstruct): void {
        if(node instanceof lambda.CfnFunction ) {
            const vars = node.environment 
            // how to use vars to get environment variables?

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First cast the `IConstruct` to the concrete `CfnFunction` type. It has a public `environment` property:

```js
const vars = (node as lambda.CfnFunction).environment;
```

The `vars` will typically be a [Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html) value.  Resolve it.

```js
const resolved: lambda.CfnFunction.EnvironmentProperty | undefined = Stack.of(node).resolve(vars);
```

Putting it all together:

```js
class LambdaEnvAspect implements IAspect {
  visit(node: IConstruct): void {
    if (node instanceof lambda.CfnFunction) {
      const vars = (node as lambda.CfnFunction).environment;
      const resolved: lambda.CfnFunction.EnvironmentProperty | undefined = Stack.of(node).resolve(vars);

      console.log(resolved?.variables);
    }
  }
}
```

When the Aspect is applied, given Lambda env vars defined as `environment: { FOO: "bar", QUEUE_ARN: queue.queueArn }` we get something like:

```js
Aspects.of(this).add(new LambdaEnvAspect());

// -> { FOO: 'bar', QUEUE_ARN: { 'Fn::GetAtt': [ 'Queue4A7E3555', 'Arn' ] } }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. How can I add all the environment variables from all the functions in an Object or Map and use it in an AWS service, for example, ssm parameter? Basically I want to export all the environment variables and their values in a ssm parameter

Comment: If `resolved.variables` is defined, add a `new ssm.StringParameter` with the stringified value.  The scope is `node` or `Stack.of(node)`.

Comment: How do I get the `resolved.variables` in a child construct? I must add the value when the `visit()` method traversed all the child constructs in the tree, right?

Comment: @Levi - Adding the string param constructor where the `console.log` is will produce one parameter per Lambda.  Offhand, I don't know whether a one-param-for-all-lambdas is possible with Aspects.

Comment: I am thinking of creating a class variable in `LambdaEnvAspect` to collect the environment variables of all lambda functions into a single object. I am not sure how or where I should retrieve the class variable of `LambdaEnvAspect` to be exported to a ssm parameter.